# Watchdog configuration Raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, debian

My plan is to configure the file `/etc/watchdog.conf` to detect if the process that I want is down and reboot the system to run again. For example, I work on a Raspberry Pi 3 in Debian 9. I would like the Raspberry is playing videos constantly and if the process is stoped for any reason, the watchdog detects it and reboot the system. I have a lot of doubts about it. On a terminal, I execute this commands:

```
modprobe bcm2708_wdog
modprobe bcm2835_wdt
echo "bcm2835_wdt" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
chkconfig watchdog on
nano /etc/watchdog.conf
```

How i can do it? how i can configure it?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How i can do it? how i can configure it? this is my question. Thanks u :D

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `/etc/watchdog.conf` available I assume you have the **watchdog** package installed from the default repository with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install watchdog
```

Now with the package you should have all installed as required to run watchdog. I do not understand why do you try to fiddle with modules. After installation  and reboot look at the status with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status watchdog.service
```

It should show you that the watchdog is running properly and report what does it check (files, interfaces, timeout, temperature, etc.).

Now you only have to configure `/etc/watchdog.conf`. How to do it you will find information with `man watchdog` and in `/usr/share/doc/watchdog/`.